# Switching from disc to downloaded game and retaining save games on the PS3 and Vita

Tags: ps3, ps-vita, playstation-plus

I recently subscribed to the Playstation Plus service and a bunch of games I have are available for free with the service. My question is this: If I download the game from the store will I be able to resume where I left off, i.e, will my save games be intact? (PS3 and Vita)

The games I am interested in are:

- BioShock Infinite - PS3
- Uncharted - Vita

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the game, I'm afraid.

Some Vita games store their saves on the cartridge, rather than the console, and some of the download versions of games on PS+ aren't the exact same version as those sold at retail, so the saves aren't always compatible/accessible.

That said, unless your downloads are capped, then you've nothing to loose by trying.

Comment: I think I will give it a try. I have edited the question to add the games I am interested in.